# Are include files necessary in an html website?

Tags: include, ssi

Are include files, such as server side include SSI, files necessary in an html website?

I recently tried to host my simple html website through GoDaddy. I used Dreamweaver CC to upload my files and encountered a problem. Some of my pages were not displaying images or css. I checked to see if the images and css were on the server and in the correct places and they were. Confused, I called GoDaddy's customer service, waited 35 minutes, and talked to one of their customer service reps. He basically told me that it may be my code and that I need 'include' files.

I have looked all over the web and I'm still not entirely sure what an include file is... I got from  my research that they are snips of code that call images/files without having to write out the same thing on every page. If I have copied and pasted the same thing on every page, why then would I need an 'include' file? I previously had my website hosted through Hostmonster, still do now, and I have never had to alter my code...

I am still new to the world of coding, so please be kind. If anyone knows of a good resource to help explain the use of 'include' files please post it or correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the GoDaddy "support" guy was talking about the `include` operation in your html files that you need to fetch your css files.

Presumably your web pages work correctly when you display them locally on your development machine -- the machine where you run Dreamweaver.  If not, fix them. They'll probably need css files in some subdirectory (or maybe in the same directory as the html) and image files in some other subdirectory.

Open up your page, on the server, in a browser, and then do View Source.  Look for your css file download commands ... which may look something like this ... in your source.

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Are the links (the href items) what you thought they should be? Sometimes you'll find that they are absolute links like

```
file:\\d\myfiles\website\dreamweaver\some_other_junk\styles\foo.css
```

If they are you need to change them to

```
 styles/foo.css
```

The same goes for images.

And, no, you don't need server-side include files to put up a working static web site.

Comment: The include operation could be what he meant, which makes more sense, but my website has been working correctly for 2 years. I double checked to make sure just now and all the html files correctly link with href tags and img tags.